# Can i parameterize the background for 2 scenarios in the same feature file

Tags: cucumber

Can I run same feature file with 2 different backgrounds? Can I parameterize the background for 2 scenarios.

Following is the feature file :

```
@Smoke
Feature: Login to the application

Background: 
Given Launch "<Browser_type>" Browser

Scenario: Logging into the application
Given I open the application
|Application_Name|
|Kohls           |
|Gymboree        |
Then I give username and password
|Username     |Password|
|abc@yahoo.com|1234|
|def@yahoo.com|5678|
When I click submit button
Then I enter into my application page

Scenario: Logging into the application
Given I open the application
|Application_Name|
|Kohls           |
|Gymboree        |
Then I give username and password
|Username     |Password|
|abc@yahoo.com|1234|
|def@yahoo.com|5678|
When I click submit button
Then I enter into my application page

Examples:
|Browser_type    |
|Chrome          |
|Firefox         |
```

When I executed it, I got an error as

> java.lang.RuntimeException: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Error parsing feature file Login.feature

Comment: are you able to resolve the issue??

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this use Scenario Outline and remove background in the feature

Example:

```
@Smoke Feature: Login to the application

Scenario Outline: Logging into the application 
Given Launch "<Browser_type>" Browser
Given I open the application 
|Application_Name| 
|Kohls |
|Gymboree | 
Then I give username and password 
|Username |Password| 
|abc@yahoo.com|1234| 
|def@yahoo.com|5678| 
When I click submit button 
Then I enter into my application page

Examples: 
|Browser_type | 
|Chrome | 
|Firefox |

Scenario Outline: Logging into the application 
Given Launch "<Browser_type>" Browser
Given I open the application 
|Application_Name| 
|Kohls | 
|Gymboree | 
Then I give username and password 
|Username |Password| 
|abc@yahoo.com|1234| 
|def@yahoo.com|5678| 
When I click submit button 
Then I enter into my application page

Examples: 
|Browser_type | 
|Chrome | 
|Firefox |
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: This makes the file more fragmented as you now have multiple copies of the exact same Examples array that you have to update if you need to make a change